# Remove previous subview in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following method in `viewDidAppear` to add an `UILabel` which show today date as a subview.

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"
    let todayDate = formatter.string(from: date)

    let todayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    todayLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    todayLabel.text = "Today is " + todayDate
    self.view.addSubview(todayLabel)
```

However, when the system date is changed, a new `UILabel` is added on top of existing one:

[image]

I tried to remove the subview and add new subview again, but the problem is not solved.

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"
    let todayDate = formatter.string(from: date)

    let todayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    todayLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    self.view.addSubview(todayLabel)
    todayLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    self.view.addSubview(todayLabel)
    todayLabel.text = "Today is " + todayDate
```

How to solve this?

Comment: While it seems like `viewDidAppear` should work, you aren't mentioning a few things that may be part of the issue. (1) How is this view controller being presented? While `viewDidLoad` means exactly that, a simple "system date is changed" doesn't trigger it again. Maybe that's the real issue. (2) Have you tried other view lifecycle events? (3) In a bigger context, what is it you are trying to do? For now, you really haven't provided enough code to actually duplicate the issue you're facing.

Comment: Give the label a tag.  Then enumerate subviews on self.view to find the label with that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your attempt to remove the old label and add the new label:

> ```
> let todayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
> todayLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
> self.view.addSubview(todayLabel)
> todayLabel.removeFromSuperview()
> self.view.addSubview(todayLabel)
> todayLabel.text = "Today is " + todayDate
> ```

But here's what your code does:

1. Create a new label, referenced by the local variable `todayLabel`.
2. Add the new label to the root view.
3. Remove the new label from from the root view.
4. Add the new label to the root view.

At no point do you ever do anything to any labels created in earlier calls to `viewDidAppear`.

Why create a new label at all? I recommend you create a label once, the first time you need it, and reuse it as needed:

```
// Cached reference to the label, if it exists
private var _todayLabel: UILabel?

// Creates the label on demand.
private var todayLabel: UILabel {
    if let label = _todayLabel { return label }
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    _todayLabel = label
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}

private var todayText: String {
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    todayLabel.text = "Today is " + todayText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are removing the new label that is created but not added as subview and then you are removing that label that is, obviously, not going to work.

**Solution:**

Whenever you are adding a new label you can create it as property or assign a tag to a label.

- Using Property as demonstrated by `rob mayoff`
- Assigning tag to label

  ```
  let todayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))

  todayLabel.tag = 1001 // or any other number you want to assign

  todayLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
  todayLabel.text = "Today is " + todayDate
  self.view.addSubview(todayLabel)
  ```
- Before adding a new label you can remove it by tag number.

  ```
  self.view.viewWithTag(1001).removeFromSuperview()
  // code here...to add a new label
  ```